# SQL Server 2008 R2 fails on cast varchar->time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I encountered a weird error in our SQL Server 2008 R2 server. The cast of a `varchar` to `time` fails depending on what other columns are used in `SELECT` clause of the top level statement. Code to reproduce the issue

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[explode]
(
    @haystack varchar(max),
    @separator varchar(8000)
)
RETURNS 
@ret TABLE 
(
    orderCol int identity(1,1),
    value varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @index bigint
    set @index = charindex(@separator,@haystack)
    while @index > 0
    begin
        insert into @ret (value) values (substring(@haystack,1,@index-1))
        set @haystack = substring(@haystack,@index+len(@separator),len(@haystack)-@index-len(@separator)+1)
        set @index = charindex(@separator,@haystack)
    end
    insert into @ret (value) select @haystack
    RETURN 
END
```

And the query:

```sql
declare @s varchar(1000) = 'a,2015-10-08,1451,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11;a,2015-10-08,1721,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22'
declare @units varchar(1000) = 'l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11'
set @units = '@label,@date,@hour,'+@units
;with cte as (select b.value,c.value as unit, a.orderCol as ri from dbo.explode(@s,';') a
cross apply dbo.explode(value,',') b
inner join dbo.explode(@units,',') c
    on b.orderCol = c.orderCol),
topCte as (
select c4.unit as unit
    ,convert(varchar,(case 
        when len(c3.value) <= 3 then '0' + substring(c3.value,1,1) + ':' + substring(c3.value,2,2) 
        else (substring(c3.value,1,2) + ':' + substring(c3.value,3,2))
        end+':00'),108) as [time]
    ,c1.value as label
    ,c2.value as [Date]
    ,c4.value
from cte c1
inner join cte c2
    on c1.ri = c2.ri and c1.unit = '@label' and c2.unit = '@date'
inner join cte c3
    on c1.ri = c3.ri and c3.unit = '@hour'
inner join cte c4
    on c1.ri = c4.ri and c4.unit not in ('@label','@date','@hour')
)
select unit, label, [date], value, cast([time] as time)
from topCte
```

This will fail with:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

However when I change the last two lines into any of these, it works correctly:

```sql
select unit, label, [date], value, [time] 
from topCte
```

```sql
select unit, label, [date], cast([time] as time)
from topCte
```

I would like to stress that I'm fully aware that this code is sub optimal and I know how to rework this so to avoid the error by rewriting the code still fullfilling business requirement. However this error shouldn't occur in this way and I'm very curious what is triggering it.

Comment: What's the value of `time`?

Comment: You say you know it is suboptimal and you know how to fix it. That function needs a complete rewrite. It looks like a form of a splitter that is loop based. I would start by fixing that. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @roryap - time is generated from the two substrings of @s so the values entering the cast as [time] are '14:51:00' and '17:21:00'

Comment: @SeanLange I said I'm aware it's not the most efficient and I know how to avoid the problem however based on my understanding of how SQL Server works, this issue shouldn't happen so I wonder if it is a bug and what is underlying reason for this to happen.
I said I know how to rework the query - not how to fix it. These are 2 different things.
That function doesn't need complete rewrite because for the amount of data I'm processing with it it's efficient enough. I added it so the code is fully reproducable.
As for your alternatives - thanks for the link but the improvement offered is neglible.

Comment: I beg to differ on the improvement but that is your call.

Comment: @SeanLange I tested 3 of the functions from the page. 1 runs exactly as fast as mine (_CTE), one is incredibly slow (_XML) and one is - of course - faster (_MODEN). However for strings the size I'm working with the difference is - as I said - neglible. For strings 100 longer I can see it being improvement but at this point I just needed something working I could write in 3 minutes. The _MODEN function is not something I would think of in 3 minutes and I wonder how much time it took author to create it. At this stage to seek for solution like _moden would be premature optimization.

Comment: Premature optimization if this was the only time you ever need a splitter. I have been using the actual Moden version, not the one posted there, for years. It has grown and improved over time thanks to the community at sql server central. As I said, I would highly recommend it but that is your call. The real problem is when others see your splitter and use it for really long strings on large tables. The performance suddenly emerges like a fiery dragon with people freaking out. Been there, done that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is something wrong in how SQL Server runs the upper query.
I would store the result into a Temporary Table and then cast the result as desired

```
create table #table_name
(
    unit varchar(3),
    label varchar(10),
    [date] varchar(10),
    value varchar(10),
    [time] varchar(10),
)


declare @s varchar(1000) = 'a,2015-10-08,1451,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11;a,2015-10-08,1721,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22'
declare @units varchar(1000) = 'l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11'
set @units = '@label,@date,@hour,'+@units
;with cte as (select b.value,c.value as unit, a.orderCol as ri from dbo.explode(@s,';') a
cross apply dbo.explode(value,',') b
inner join dbo.explode(@units,',') c
    on b.orderCol = c.orderCol),
topCte as (
select c4.unit as unit
    ,(case 
        when len(c3.value) <= 3 then '0' + substring(c3.value,1,1) + ':' + substring(c3.value,2,2) 
        else (substring(c3.value,1,2) + ':' + substring(c3.value,3,2))
        end+':00') as [time]
    ,c1.value as label
    ,c2.value as [Date]
    ,c4.value
from cte c1
inner join cte c2
    on c1.ri = c2.ri and c1.unit = '@label' and c2.unit = '@date'
inner join cte c3
    on c1.ri = c3.ri and c3.unit = '@hour'
inner join cte c4
    on c1.ri = c4.ri and c4.unit not in ('@label','@date','@hour')
)
insert into #table_name(unit, label, [date], value, [time])
select unit, label, [date], value,  [time] 
from topCte

select unit, label, [date], value, cast([time] as time) 
from #table_name
```

Comment: Yes - that much I did as quick and dirty work around the problem. It just baffles me how SQL Server hits the error. Not 2nd to last remark - if I just remove [value] from the final select, it works.

Comment: Ok, good. My advice, is to rewrite the query and use temporary tables for your 'a', 'b', 'c', 'cte', 'topCte'.  You'll have much more control and the code will be much more 'readable'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your case expression for the [time] column. If you remove the cast in the select statement you will see values like 14:51:00 which is invalid for time. You are initially converting to a varchar but you don't specify the size which is another issue. There really is no need to convert this to a varchar because it is already a varchar value.

Here is a working version of your code.

```
declare @s varchar(1000) = 'a,2015-10-08,1451,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11;a,2015-10-08,1721,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22'
declare @units varchar(1000) = 'l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11'
set @units = '@label,@date,@hour,'+@units
;with cte as (select b.value,c.value as unit, a.orderCol as ri from dbo.explode(@s,';') a
cross apply dbo.explode(value,',') b
inner join dbo.explode(@units,',') c
    on b.orderCol = c.orderCol),
topCte as (
select c4.unit as unit
    ,
    case 
        when len(c3.value) <= 3 then '0' + substring(c3.value,1,1) + ':' + substring(c3.value,2,2) 
        else (substring(c3.value,1,2) + ':' + substring(c3.value,3,2))
        end
    as [time]

    ,c1.value as label
    ,c2.value as [Date]
    ,c4.value
from cte c1
inner join cte c2
    on c1.ri = c2.ri and c1.unit = '@label' and c2.unit = '@date'
inner join cte c3
    on c1.ri = c3.ri and c3.unit = '@hour'
inner join cte c4
    on c1.ri = c4.ri and c4.unit not in ('@label','@date','@hour')
)
select unit, label, [date], value, cast([time] as time)
from topCte
```

Comment: Actually it gives me the error as well: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.". Also - when you don't put length or character type to convert, it defaults to 30 - that's in specification for SQL Server.

Comment: Also why is 14:51:00 invalid for time? This works: select cast('14:51:00' as time)

Comment: Yes the default length is specified but the default length also changes based on usage. Why rely on defaults when being explicit is just a couple keystrokes. And yes you are correct that is valid for time. Oddly this code runs with issue on my system using your function and supplied sample data.

Comment: What do you mean - default length also changes based on usage? Defaults are there to use. As I'm casting the value - eventually - to time I couldn't possibly have a string >30 characters long that's castable to time. I'm not against saying explicitly that nobody should use explicit values, but this is one of the details that's just irrelevant here.

Comment: Well when it is a variable it is 30. But if it is a column it is 1. It stinks but that is what we have to live with. You can read more about using default lengths here. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length I have made a couple suggestions to you about improving your code and you don't seem to want take my advice so I will refrain helping in that area.

Comment: As to why this code is throwing an error, do you have more data is causing this to fail. It runs just fine on my system.